# Multi hierarchical relationships database diagram

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, erd

My goal is to create a database with a hierarchy as shown below on ERD.
I'm not sure what I created is correct.
[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUMyR.png)

Edit:
I'm going to create LMS where the course structure will look like that:
Course type(e.g. basic, extended) -> License(e.g. A1, A2)->Module(e.g Math, Chemistry) -> Chapter(e.g Algebra)->Subchatper(e.g equations)->Lessons

Every lesson has questions with answers.
For chapters and subchapters, there are exams with questions from lessons

Comment: there is no way to answer this question.  Based on the names of the tables, this will not work as you expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.